Roots of $x^2+x+2$ over $\mathbb{Z}_3[X](i)$
As the polynomial $f(x)=x^2+x+2$ is irreducible, then
$$
\mathbb{Z}_3[X]/\langle f(x) \rangle = \{p(x)+\langle f(x) \rangle \: : \: p(x) \in \mathbb{Z}_3[X]\} =  \{ax+b+\langle f(x) \rangle \: : \: a,b \in \mathbb{Z}_3\}
$$
and calling $\beta=x+\langle f(x) \rangle$. I came up to
$$
x^2+x+2 = (x-\beta)(x+\beta+1)
$$
But a friend of mine told me that $\mathbb{Z}_3[X]/\langle f(x) \rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}_3[X](i)$.
I don't really see how that isomorphism follows (may be using the fact that both are extensions of degree over $\mathbb{Z}_3[X]$). Neither how can I guess the roots in that field, may I build the isomorphism to guess the roots in the new field? I'll appreciate any advice. Thanks in advance.


Write either everywhere $X$ or everywhere $x$. Do not use two distinct letters for the same object (the polynomial indeterminate). 2) Even so, your title doesn't make sense. 3) Neither does "both are extensions of degree over $\mathbb{Z}_3[X]$".


@AnneBauval 1) $X$ stands for the ring, as $x$ does for the variable of the polynomial. Definitely not the same thing. 2) The question remarks how to find the roots of the polynomial in the given field. And the text suggests finding an isomorphism to guess them. 3) $\mathbb{Z}_3[X]/\langle f(x) \rangle$ and $\mathbb{Z}_3X$ are both extensions of degree 2 over $\mathbb{Z}_3$.


"$X$ stands for the ring"? which ring? $\Bbb Z_3[X]$ is a polynomial ring, and the "variable of the polynomial" $f$ is definitely the same thing: $f(X)$ is an element of this ring, and we quotient the ring by the ideal generated by this element. We neither write "$\mathbb{Z}_3[X]/\langle f(x)$" nor "$p(x) \in \mathbb{Z}_3[X]$". 2) The title makes no sense. There are no roots of $f(X)$ "over $\Bbb Z_3X$". 3) Even with your replacement of "both extensions of degree over" by "both extensions of degree $2$ of", this is false (see the beginning of my answer).


Your friend was nearly correct. $A:=\Bbb Z_3[X]/\langle f(X) \rangle$ is a finite field (with $9$ elements). It cannot be isomorphic to the infinite ring $\mathbb{Z}_3[X](i)$, but it is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_3[i]=\Bbb Z_3(i)$.
Indeed, with your notation $\beta=X+\langle f(X)\rangle$, the two roots of $f$ in $A$ are $\beta$ and $\gamma:=-\beta-1$. Since
$\beta+\gamma=-1$ and $\beta\gamma=2$, we have
$$(2\beta+1)^2=(\beta-\gamma)^2=(\beta+\gamma)^2-4\beta\gamma=-7=-1$$
hence
$$A=\Bbb Z_3[\beta]=\Bbb Z_3[i],\text{ where }i:=2\beta+1=-\beta+1.$$

To find the roots observe that the polynomial $f(x)=x^2+x+2 \in \mathbb{Z}_3[X]$ is irreducible because $\mathbb{Z}_3$ is a field (as $3$ is prime), $f(x)$ has degree 2 with no roots in $\mathbb{Z}_3$ ($f(0),f(1),f(2)\neq 0 ) $.
Nonetheless, $f(x)$ splits in $\mathbb{Z}_3[X](i)$. In order to find its roots we apply the quadratic formula
$$
x=\frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{1-4\cdot 1 \cdot 2}}{2\cdot 1} = 2 \cdot (2 \pm \sqrt{-7})
$$
because $2^{-1}=2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_3$, and $-7=-1$ so
$$
x=1 \pm 2\sqrt{-1} = 1 \pm 2i
$$
And it follows
$$
(x-(1+2i))(x-(1-2i)) = (x-1)^2-(2i)^2 = x^2-2x+1+4
$$
which is $x^2+x+2 = f(x)$.
Observe you can use the quadratic formula because you are on a field, in particular, it is enough to check that commutative property holds
$$
x^2+ax+b=0 \iff (x+\frac{a}{2})^2 = \frac{a^2-4b}{4}
$$
from which follows
$$
x= \frac{-a \pm\sqrt{a^2-4b}}{2a}
$$
the quadratic formula that we can extend to $ax^2+bx+c$, by dividing by $\frac{1}{a}$.

You wrongly mixed the notations $x$ and $X$, like the OP (see 1st comment above).

A petty nitpicking: the quadratic formula works because we're working with a field of characteristic $\neq 2$.

$x= \frac{-a \pm\sqrt{a^2-4b}}2$, not $x= \frac{-a \pm\sqrt{a^2-4b}}{2a}$ (therefore, we don't need here to be on a field: we only need $2$ to be invertible).

Another remark: $f(0),f(1),f(2)\ne0$ is equivalent to: $-1$ (the discriminant) is not a square in $\Bbb Z_3$.
